# How to set a base path for SailsJS APIs?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

The sailsJS routes by default are mapped to `/` base path.

For e.g.`'get /user/getUser': 'User.getUser'`, is mapped to `/user/getUser/`

Now, I want to set a base path for API endpoints, which should be dynamic.

For e.g. `'get /user/getUser': 'User.getUser'` should map to `/api/user/getUser/` , while the `/api/` string should be dynamic.

I am unable to set this key name dynamically, like `get ${apiBase}/user/getUser`.

Is there any way to set the base path for APIs in SailsJS (v1.0.2)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by editing your `config/blueprints.js` config file. Add:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    prefix: '/api',
};
```

If you otherwise have blueprints turned on, then this will map all controller actions. A `User.getUser` controller action is now reachable at `{yoururl}/api/user/getUser` without any further configuration of routes.

Of course, if you override any of these in your `routes.js` file, then the prefix `/api` is not automatically used.

That said, I can't see any impediment to getting and using that in your `routes.js` file:

```
var prefix = require('./blueprints.js').blueprints.prefix || '/';
module.exports.routes = {
    // ...
    'GET ' + prefix + '/user/getUser/:id': 'UserController.getUser',
};
```

docs on blueprint config are here: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints